# How to iterate through Playlist using foreachLoop?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-3.0

I have following playlist:

```
Playlist playList = new Playlist();
```

I am adding the playList ietms to my playList as below:

```
if (strmediaExtension == "wmv" || strmediaExtension == "mp4" || strmediaExtension == "mp3" || strmediaExtension == "mpg")
                {
                    PlaylistItem playListItem = new PlaylistItem();
                    string thumbSource = folderItems.strAlbumcoverImage;
                    playListItem.MediaSource = new Uri(strmediaURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                    playListItem.Title = folderItems.strAlbumName;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbSource))
                        playListItem.ThumbSource = new Uri(thumbSource, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                    playList.Items.Add(playListItem);
                }
```

Now suppose my plaList has 9 Items inside it . I want to iterate through each by using `foreach` loop as following:

```
foreach (PlaylistItem p in playList)
                    { 
                    //Code Goes here
                    }
```

But I am getting the errror:

*foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ExpressionMediaPlayer.Playlist' because 'ExpressionMediaPlayer.Playlist' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'*

Can any one please explain why this is happening and what is the correct way of doing it.

Thanks,
Subhhen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have to write:

```
foreach (PlaylistItem p in playList.Items)
{ 
  //Code Goes here
}
```

Further details using foreach:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want:

```
foreach(PlaylistItem p in playList.Items)
{
    //code goes here
}
```